# How to open web console like Chrome console in Visual Studio Code preview side and see JavaScript changes dynamicaly?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, console

Main goal is that I would like to see dynamic web console, In VSCode side preview, like Chrome console in this picture ([VSCode with separate Crome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bYTs.png)) and that it will updates dynamicaly.
Now I am doing like that:

1. created index.html file and included 
   src="laikinas.js">
2. opened index.html with live server
   extension, it opened new Chrome browser window.
3. presses F12, tab "Console"
4. resized both VSCode and Chrome browser.

As you see this is long way, and if I screating new file with another name I also need to include it in index.html. Another my way was:

1. Opened VSCode debug console
2. pressed Cntr+F5

But this console I do not like. One of this that the Chrome console show errors better with links to exactly point.

I also tryed extension like this one ["Quick HTML Previewer"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=daiyy.quick-html-previewer) to see dynamic changes, but this extension can show only frontend, I need a **console**.

Comment: It's not a VScode solution but try to use https://codesandbox.io/

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest thing is using npm nodemon to watch the files on your local directory. Then when you save in VS you can refresh the page in your browser to see the changes you made. Not quite as nice as chrome because of the extra clicks.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4N0d8HhU5DE